# Find the Slopes and Y-intercepts.

Tags: linear-algebra

Im currently doing an Algebra course on a site, and in the test I'm currently on these problems are stablished.

What are the slopes and y-coordinates of the y-intercepts of the following lines.

$$a)\ \ y=-3x+2$$

$$b) \ \ 2y=-3x+2$$

$$c) \ \ 5y=2-3x$$

$$d) \ \ y+3x-2=0$$

And as the slope intercept form is $y=mx+b$

My results were...

a) -3x / (0,2)

b) -1.5x / (0,1)

c) -0.6x / (0,.4)

d) -3x / (0,2)

But apparently they are wrong...
Can someone explain me what could be wrong over here?.. Thanks!

EDIT : The slopes must not contain the x , and the y-intercepts are a single number not a coordinate. Thanks to @user84413 that helped me on the comments.

Comment: You have the right idea; you just want to omit the "x" when you write the slopes, and you just want to give the y-coordinate for the y-intercepts.

Comment: Yes!!! @user84413 thanks a lot! I was so upset about this the entire freaking night! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got all of the numerical answers correct.

With the equation $y=mx+b$, the slope is $m$ and the $y$-intercept is $b$.

The slope is the coefficient on the $x$ term if the equation is in this form.  In other words, it's the value that multiplies $x$.

The $y$-intercept is the value of $y$ on the line when $x=0$.  So $y = m(0) + b = b.$

To clarify, though, the *point* at which the $y$-intercept is located is indeed $(0,b)$.

Answer (score 1):

All ur answers are correct but it must given like,

a) m=-3x / b=2

b) m=-1.5 / b=1

c) m=-0.6 / b=0.4

d) m=-3 / b=2